# My family setup

Tags: cortana, parental-control

What is the use of my family to download an app. It's a waste of time because every time I want to download an app, it shows something about MY FAMILY SETUP NEEDED. When I am done with my setup I try and download an app that message appears again. 
So what must I Do Now